# For each element in one sorted numpy array, how to subtract the smallest greater value in another sorted array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say we have two sorted numpy arrays, `a` and `b`.

```
a = np.array([ 0,  1,  2, 10])
b = np.array([ 7, 13])
```

For each element array `a`, I want to subtract the first larger element in `b` to get something like this:

```
>>> f(a, b)
array([-7, -6, -5, -3])
```

I can do this with an inefficient for loop, but is there a more numpythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for this. It will require that `b` is sorted and that `a` doesn't have values greater than the largest in `b`.

```
> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 10, 12, 5, 7])
> b = np.array([7, 13])
> a - b[np.searchsorted(b, a, side='right')]

array([-7, -6, -5, -3, -1, -2, -6])
```

Answer (score 0):

The title and explanations are inconsistent.

Assuming that you're looking for the **first** element of `b` that is larger, not the **smallest** of `b` that is larger, then this will do it:

```
a - b[np.argmax(a[:,None]<b,axis=1)]

# array([-7, -6, -5, -3])
```

If you do need the **smallest** that is larger, you could sort `b` beforehand using `b = np.sort(b)` but then, using searchsorted(), as proposed by Mark Meyer, will be more efficient.

*note that you must have at least one element in `b` that is larger than the largest element of `a`*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the title and explanation are inconsistent. I just clarified that both arrays are sorted.